# SynchronousOnlyOperation error when upgrading from python 3.6 to python 3.7 using django channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-channels

I've been attempting to upgrade python from 3.6 to 3.7 for our Django & Django channels application. With that change, Django throws a `SynchronousOnlyOperation` anytime any HTTP request is made (even if it has nothing to do with WebSockets). My guess is that somehow the python upgrade has made the Django check more strict.

I believe that Django channels are serving both the HTTP requests and WebSocket requests so it expects all code to be async compliant.

How do I get Django channels `runserver` to run the `wsgi` app synchronously, while the channel consumers asynchronously?

```
# project/asgi.py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({"http": get_asgi_application(), "websocket": routing})
```

```
# project/wsgi.py
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Stacktrace:
It's clear to me that the auth middleware that is running for a normal wsgi view is not async compliant, how can I get it to run in a sync environment?

```
ERROR    Internal Server Error: /a/api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 233, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache
AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/___/___/___/___/apps/core/middleware.py", line 60, in __call__
    request.is_user_verified = request.user.is_verified()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 240, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 376, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_otp/middleware.py", line 38, in _verify_user
    user.otp_device = None
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 270, in __setattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 376, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 12, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 174, in get_user
    user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 58, in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 238, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 43, in load
    s = self._get_session_from_db()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 34, in _get_session_from_db
    expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1154, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/___/___/.pyenv/versions/pd37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Versions

```
Django==3.1.1
channels==3.0.2
channels-redis==3.2.0
```

Comment: It's hard to believe you only upgraded python, since you're using the django.auth middleware and not channels.auth.

Comment: My regular django views use django.auth middleware (and have been since I started using django-channels).

Comment: So I guess this is a runserver problem then cause you don't have this setup in production and use Daphne + Gunicorn? Is it possible you upgraded channels from 2 to 3 as a side-effect when you upgraded python?

Comment: That's correct, I run daphne + gunicorn in production. I tried getting runserver to work on channels 2 and 3, neither worked. Currently running channels 3 in production on python 3.6

Comment: Do you have "channels" in INSTALLED_APPS so you're running with the correct runserver? I cannot reproduce your problem and I'm on python 3.9.

Comment: Yes, interesting. Are you using middleware in the wsgi part of the app that leverages the database? I.e. database backed sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this. For us, we were using `gevent` and had this line in our manage.py

```
# manage.py

import gevent

gevent.patch_all()
```

For whatever reason, that does not play nicely with python 3.7+, Django channels, and Django (where python 3.6, Django channels, and Django worked fine).

We were lucky and were able to remove this from our codebase; we did not figure out how to fix the `gevent` patch.

Answer (score 1):

So a summary of what I've tried:

- First, I have a channels app that had no database at all, no contrib apps except staticfiles.
- I added database, DRF and one app with a single model and list/detail views
- Enabled the sync http consumer:

```
# dwtools.routing
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import romanize.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "websocket": URLRouter(romanize.routing.websocket_urlpatterns),
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
    },
)
```

- settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "channels",
    "romanize.apps.RomanizeConfig",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "agencies.apps.AgenciesConfig",
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = "dwtools.wsgi.application"
ASGI_APPLICATION = "dwtools.routing.application"
```

I can pull up DRF's standard views, create entries etc.

Then added a simple middleware that accesses the database (gets a count of the number of Agencies and puts it in request). Not even using MiddlewareMixin, just barebones init can call protocol.

```py
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 07, 2020 - 14:38:56
Django version 3.1.4, using settings 'dwtools.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.2 development server at http://127.0.0.1:3401/
#             ^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^ ( Channels runserver)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
HTTP GET /agencies/ 200 [0.05, 127.0.0.1:60460]
```

The stack uses local nginx to route to port 3401 for `/ws` (websocket) and `/agencies` (http). Perhaps you spot something...

Comment: Thanks for going through this setup. I think the big difference here is that I'm just running `runserver` (for local development) vs setting up nginx

Comment: What you see is nginx routing to `runserver`. If I directly go to port 3401, then I also have no problems.

Comment: Thanks again for the help here, in the end, it had to do with gevent ‍♂️ see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451624/835696